# Help with power and fuses (diagram)

Tags: power, fuses

I am not familiar with using fuses and working with such high amperage. Can someone help to see if my diagram is Ok especially where the fuses are placed and the amperage of the fuses used? Feel free to ask me any questions about the devices used. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the NUC can't use 12V directly? Also, you've left no wiggle room for the fuses.

Comment: Won't your top rocker switch short out your battery?

Comment: Hi Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, I've read server forums that the power might not be stable and might get power off when using 12V even though the specs says 12-19V. I have use the Intel NUC successfully before using a 19V 3.5A Laptop power bank.

Comment: Hi Tyler,  I am basing the rocker switch wiring on http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/SPST-rocker-switch-wiring.php

Comment: The number one purpose of a fuse is to prevent wire from starting fires. For this reason, fuse sizes should be based on wire diameter. And thus, you should add wire diameter to your diagram. There are different systems for wire diameter (AWG, mm, and others). Use whichever one you want.

Comment: Fuses also typically need to be de-rated. This is a big topic by itself, but the idea is that if the load uses 5A continuously, you don't want to use a 5A fuse. The fuse will need to be a bit larger to avoid nuisance blowing. If the operating temperature is high, that can require additional de-rating. Then there is inrush current. If your load has large capacitors that charge up every time power is applied, that can also cause nuisance blowing of the fuse.

Comment: Do you really have a rocker switch rated for 50A at 12V DC? I am sure they exist, but I expect that would be a very large and expensive rocker switch.

Comment: Yes mkeith, its hard to find 50A 12V rocker switch. I've yet to find it. Currently, the largest I found is 30A so far. Maybe I need an alternative type of switch

Comment: Guest makes battery switches, but they are huge.

Comment: Add a relay and a switch with a smaller rating instead? Finding a 50A+ relay should not be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a circuit intended to run 50A, I would be looking at a 75A fuse, with wiring and switch gear to suit!

You never want to fuse at your design rated load current, that will be horrible from a long term reliability perspective, and especially in low voltage systems you will generally find that it is voltage drop and not heating that should define your cable sizes, and since fuses basically exist to protect cables, you should size the fuse to the cable current rating not the load current rating (Which will be lower due to the aforementioned voltage drop considerations).

One does not (In general) protect loads with fuses, they are just way to slow, unless you buy the stupidly expensive semiconductor rated ones and even then...

Be careful with switches, you will often find that they have a DC rating very much lower then the AC one.

My (fairly random) rule of thumb is that fuses should be sized 50% over the maximum expected RMS load current and cables then sized to the fuse or voltage drop whichever causes the larger cable size.

Comment: 50A may be quite a bit over the normal operating current. It looks like the OP got to 50 by assuming both motors are stalled at the same time. Also, the OP is allocating 3A to arduino mega and sensors. That is probably not the normal operating current either.

Comment: Hi mkeith, I have the same thought that I may not need full 40A unless both motors stall at the same time. I did check with ServoCity where I got the motors from and they recommended 40A hence I just wanted to play it safe. The motors will be used on a wheeled platform. It is possible that both motors will be stalled at the same time. Good point about the Arduino. After some searching, others are saying that the current draw including sensors is no more than 500mA

Comment: I've sent another email to ServoCity asking them if 40A is really necessary since the wires on the motor does not seems like it could take 20A

Answer (score 3):

Fuses are primarily to protect wiring. They don't act fast enough to protect semiconductors typically.

Make sure the wire downstream of each fuse can handle the fuse current.

Also keep all possible ground current paths in mind- a 50A-fused conductor contacting a light - gauge ground conductor suitable for 3A coils could cause fireworks.

I don't think you should connect the other side of the rocker switch to ground- just leave it open- unless it is the lamp connection on an illuminated switch.

Comment: Thanks Spehro Pefhany for the feedback. Some have suggested that the fuse be slightly under the rated load since they do not act as fast. Yes, the rocker switch has an LED

Comment: You can get nuisance fuse blowing if the fuses are undersized. Since the purpose is to protect the wiring there is no problem going a over as Dan Mills suggests. Think of your home wiring- you may have 30A wiring and fuse or circuit breaker for a 1A load.